# ASP.NET lisbox - Selected first item, always

Tags: asp.net, listbox, selecteditem

I have a list box which is populated using a dictioanry. When I iterate throught the selected items using the following code, it always show only the first items as selected - even if the first item is not selected.

Have you ever encountered this scenario?

Could you please help on this?

This problem occurs when I use dictionary for binding.  On the other hand a generic list works fine.

```
 private void PopulateListBox2()
    {
        List<string> subjectList = new List<string>();
        subjectList.Add("Maths");
        subjectList.Add("Science");

        ListBox1.DataSource = subjectList;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }
```

---

Even it will work fine, if the values are unique. But in my scenario, the values are same; only key varies. The following works

```
 private void PopulateListBox5()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        resultDictionary.Add("Maths", "Lijo1");
        resultDictionary.Add("Science", "Lijo2");

        ListBox1.DataValueField = "Value";
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "Key";

        ListBox1.DataSource = resultDictionary;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The following code has the problem.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateListBox1();
            ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListBox1()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        resultDictionary.Add("Maths", "Lijo");
        resultDictionary.Add("Science", "Lijo");

        ListBox1.DataValueField = "Value";
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "Key";

        ListBox1.DataSource = resultDictionary;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MakeList1Items();
    }

    private void MakeList1Items()
    {
        string test = null;

        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))
                {
                    test=item.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    test = test +", " + item.Text;
                }

            }
        } 
        Response.Write(test);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: Where does this code occur in the page life cycle?

Comment: This event comes under a function that is called in button click's event handler.

Comment: So it's in the click handler for the button?  You might want to update your question with more of the surrounding code.  There's really not much to go on here.  Also, remember to use the `010 101` button or indent your code 4 spaces to get it to format properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` of the ListBox the wrong way around. I'm not sure *why*, but they must be like this:

```
ListBox1.DataValueField = "Key";
ListBox1.DataTextField = "Value";
```

So, in reality, you are best not using a Dictionary for for this kind of binding. Maybe try a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` instead.

Comment: No. It did not work. I have updated the original question with more details.

Comment: It **does** work. I copied your code, switched the "Key" and "Value" around, and both were output. They need to be that way around.